# Problem with listings package using stix fonts

Tags: fonts, listings, stix

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstdefinelanguage{test}{sensitive=true,
  morekeywords={TEST},
morecomment=[l]{--}}
\lstnewenvironment{testcode}
{\lstset{breaklines=true,language=test, basicstyle=\color{blue}\tiny}}
{}
\begin{document}
\begin{testcode}
TEST

-- Testing 8*8=64
\end{testcode}
\end{document}
```

compiling with `pdflatex` gives the following output:

[image]

As seen, the asterix `*` does not show up in the `listings` comment..

If I don't use the `stix` package, it works fine:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look in the log file, you see the origin of the problem:

```
Missing character: There is no * in font ts1-stixgeneral-italic!
```

This happens as soon as you try to output an italic `*` with `listings`. That's because `listings` tries to substitute `*` with `\textasteriskcentered` which unfortunately doesn't exist in the right variant when using the current stix fonts release ([STIXv1.1.0-latex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stixfonts/files/Current%20Release/)). A simple workaround is to redefine `\textasteriskcentered` to be a mathematical `*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\renewcommand{\textasteriskcentered}{\ensuremath{*}}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\itshape}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Testing 8*8=64
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```